# Unable to send an array through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a javascript that sends an array through AJAX to a server side PHP script.

I am attaching relevant code snippets of my javascript AJAX function below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "bar2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{data:x},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(status);console.log(error);
   },
        success:function(data){
//do stuff
}
}
    );
```

x is my array which I am sending.

I access this array in my PHP script as shown below:

```
    $data = $_REQUEST['data'];
    $len = $data.length;

    $x=format_array($data);
    function format_array($data){
      return "'" . implode("', '", $data) . "'";
    }
    $myquery = "
    select state,count(device_id) as c_num from base_data where state               

     IN($x)group by state order by c_num DESC limit 10;
      ";
      $query = mysql_query($myquery);
```

But when I run it I get the error:
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in **** on line 16

Please help. I have spent an hour on this and am not able to figure it out. Am I sending the data in the correct way?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your array to JSON then send it to PHP (server side):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "bar2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(x)},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(status);console.log(error);
        },
        success:function(data){
            //do stuff
        }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['data']);
$len = count($data);
//.....
//.....
```

Comment: this is not necessary, should be no problem receiving form endoded data as array

Answer (score 2):

Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and you will receive as array of form encoded data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) which is `$.ajax` default

Also use `count()` instead of `length` in php